# Save the image path in the database

Tags: laravel, filepath, image-upload

I have functions for saving pictures

Functions in the model

```
public function getOriginMainImageUrl()
    {
        return $this->attributes['main_image'];
    }

    public function getMainImageAttribute($value)
    {
        return Storage::exists($value) ? Storage::url($value) : null;
    }

    public function getOriginPreviewImageUrl()
    {
        return $this->attributes['preview_image'];
    }

    public function getPreviewImageAttribute($value)
    {
        return Storage::exists($value) ? Storage::url($value) : null;
    }
```

Controller

```
if ($request->hasFile('main_image')) {
   $file = $request->file('main_image');
   $namewithextension = $file->getClientOriginalName();
   $name = explode('.', $namewithextension)[0];
   $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $uploadname = $name. '-' .DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(TRUE))->format('U-u') . '.' .$extension;
   $article_block_image->main_image = $file->storeAs('public/article-block-image/main', $uploadname);
}

if ($request->hasFile('preview_image')) {
   $file = $request->file('preview_image');
   $namewithextension = $file->getClientOriginalName();
   $name = explode('.', $namewithextension)[0];
   $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $uploadname = $name. '-' .DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(TRUE))->format('U-u') . '.' .$extension;
   $path = public_path('storage/article-block-image/preview/'. $uploadname);
   Image::make($file)->resize(240, 120)->save($path);
}
```

For the first one, I use `storeAs` and I get the path to the picture in the database, for the second I had to use `resize` with `intervention/image`, and I save there through `save` and i dont get the path to this picture in db

Here's what I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjKaL.jpg

The question is how to get the path for `preview_image`

I tried something like

```
$path = public_path('storage/article-block-image/preview/'. $uploadname);
$img = Image::make($file)->resize(240, 120);
$article_block_image->preview_image = $img->save($path);
```

But I get the error

`"message": "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded", "exception": "InvalidArgumentException",`

Comment: how is the data in your DB in that example ? how do you save the $path (since you use the same variable for both) in your model ?

Comment: @N69S the data in the database is stored like this https://imgur.com/a/TYcYxfn, I save it like this `$path = public_path('storage/article-block-image/preview/'. $uploadname);
   Image::make($file)->resize(240, 120)->save($path);`

Comment: The image you linked (and stop using images in stackoverflow) is a json result after the mutators `getPreviewImageAttribute()` what i am asking about is the data directly from the database.

Comment: `$img->save($path)` before on a separate line, then just store `$path`?

Comment: @N69S yes, I understand you need to first remove these mutators `getOriginPreviewImageUrl(), getPreviewImageAttribute($value)`, then do `$article_block_image->preview_image = '/storage/article-block-image/preview/'. $uploadname;` , and in the end I get what I need

Comment: @meow NO, do you not seek real help from us ? if so, provide more details.

Comment: @N69S I was already able to solve the problem thanks to your comment, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the model, delete the following

```
public function getOriginPreviewImageUrl()
    {
        return $this->attributes['preview_image'];
    }

public function getPreviewImageAttribute($value)
    {
        return Storage::exists($value) ? Storage::url($value) : null;
    }
```

In the controller we do this

```
$path = public_path('/storage/article-block-image/preview/'. $uploadname);
Image::make($file)->resize(240, 120)->save($path);
$article_block_image->preview_image = '/storage/article-block-image/preview/'. $uploadname;
```